# Check multiple cookies jQuery syntax

Tags: jquery, cookies, syntax

I'd like to check if one of the two cookies are set:

```
if($.cookie("c1") != 'true' || $.cookie("c2") != 'true') {
```

(and then depending on the cookie do some action, or set cookie)

Is this the proper syntax to check if either the first or the second are set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct syntax is

```
if($.cookie("c1") !== null || $.cookie("c2") !== null) {

    // one of the cookies, or both, are set

}
else {
    // none of the cookies are set

}
```

---

**from your comment**, what you are after could be something like:

```
if($.cookie("c1") !== null && $.cookie("c2") !== null) {

    // both cookies exist, let's check if they have the values we need
    if($.cookie("c1") === "true" && $.cookie("c2") === "true") {
        // they have 'true' as their content

    }
    else {
        // they might exist, but both do not hold the value 'true'

    }
}
else {
    // none, or at least one of the two cookies are not set

}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually "true" was the value of the cookies, but seeing your comment that "one of or both are set" helped me understand that my if statement won't work this way... I need to set/check a cookie with two different values depending on user select, and not set/check two cookies, I guess.

Comment: to check if both are set you should use the `AND` operator, in javascript it's 2 amp signs `&&`, that will only be jump inside the statement if only BOTH cookies exist. I have updated my answer to make this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it probably works, but not in my situation, would you mind taking a look at my code in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774625/user-select-cookie-set-check-with-jquery?]